# Company logo in an MIT licensed project

Tags: mit, trademark, logos

I want to release a project under the MIT license. Among the source files there is a png with the company logo. I would like to specify that that logo cannot be included in any of the derivative works.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a lawyer, and it might be best to consult with your company's legal department (if they have one) about this before releasing the project.

If your company's logo is a registered trademark, I don't think there is a lot to worry about. A good practice would be to explicitly state in the LICENSE or COPYING file that the logo is a registered trademark of CompanyXYZ and its use is not permitted in any derivative works.